# calling a method from ViewModel when DataContext changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

The situation:
I have a little app that works with fantasy classes. In the example below I boiled it down to the bare bones. In a ComboBox, situated in the Main Window, the user selects a fantasy class (warrior, rogue, mage etc.) from a list loaded from a DB. This information is passed to a UserControl sitting in Main Window which exposes details about the class using MVVM and data binding. All of this works so far.

The DB has a value (in this case Gear) saved as an int which at the moment displays as an int on screen. It's the app's responsibility to parse that to a string.

**So the question is:** How do I wire up a method in the UserControl's ViewModel to trigger whenever it's associated View has a DataContext (the selected CharacterClass) change?

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="ExampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Height="22" MinWidth="70" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClass}"/>
        <local:DetailsView Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedClass}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Main Window ViewModel:

```
namespace ExampleApp
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : Observable
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CharacterClass> _Classes;
        private CharacterClass _SelectedClass;

        public ObservableCollection<CharacterClass> Classes
        {
            get { return _Classes; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _Classes, value); }
        }
        public CharacterClass SelectedClass
        {
            get { return _SelectedClass; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _SelectedClass, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            LoadCharacterClasses();
        }

        private void LoadCharacterClasses()
        {
            //simulated data retrieval from a DB.
            //hardcoded for demo purposes
            Classes = new ObservableCollection<CharacterClass>
            {
                //behold: Gear is saved as an int.
                new CharacterClass { Name = "Mage", Gear = 0, Stats = "3,2,1" },
                new CharacterClass { Name = "Rogue", Gear = 1, Stats = "2,2,2" },
                new CharacterClass { Name = "Warrior", Gear = 2, Stats = "1,2,3" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

My CharacterClass definition. Inheriting from Observable which encapsulates INotifyPropertyChanged

```
namespace ExampleApp
{
    public class CharacterClass : Observable
    {
        private string _Name;
        private int _Gear;
        private string _Stats;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _Name, value); }
        }
        public int Gear
        {
            get { return _Gear; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _Gear, value); }
        }
        public string Stats
        {
            get { return _Stats; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _Stats, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Details about the Observable baseclass:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ExampleApp
{
    public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(member, val)) return;

            member = val;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The DetailsView UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExampleApp.DetailsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailsViewModel}">
            <local:DetailsView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Name:"/>
            <Label Content="Base Stats"/>
            <Label Content="Starting Gear"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Stats}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding gearToString}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and finally: the DetailsViewModel:

```
public class DetailsViewModel : Observable
    {
        public string GearToString;

        //The method I would like to have called whenever the selected
        //CharacterClass (DetailsView.DataContext, so to speak) changes.
        private void OnCharacterClassChanged(int gearNumber)
        {
            switch (gearNumber)
            {
                case 0:
                    GearToString = "Cloth";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    GearToString = "Leather";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    GearToString = "Plate";
                    break;
                default:
                    GearToString = "*Error*";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've fiddled around with attempting to have a command fire when the DetailsView Label updates.
Made a failed attempt to convert DetailsViewModel.GearToString to a dependencyproperty.
I've attempted to override Observable's SetProperty inside of DetailsViewModel.

I don't know which, if any of, those attempts would be viable, if I managed to implement them properly (I've only been coding for several months now :))

I could get it to work using DetailsView code-behind, however that's not MVVM'y.

Comment: Character has `int` Gear and you want to visualize it as a `string`. This could be achieved by using a simple converter. Another possibility is to use viewmodel: you already have `SelectedClass` property, in its setter you can run logic, which will alter another property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you change your DetailViews DataContext via the combobox, you can access the "current" DetailDataContext *before* the combobox changes SelectedItem.
You can do this right here:

```
public CharacterClass SelectedClass
{
   get { return _SelectedClass; }
   set { 
          _SelectedClass.DoWhatever();
          SetProperty(ref _SelectedClass, value); 
   }
}
```

Or you can handle the ComboBoxes SelectionChanged event via a command. Your old value is in e.RemovedItem.

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        (e.RemovedItems[0] as CharacterClass).DoSomething();
}
```

I tend to prefer that approach since it can get confusing quickly if you put too much logic in the setters. It leads to chain reactions that are pretty hard to follow and debug.

In general viewmodels communicate with each other via events. In more complex / disconnected situations with the help of an EventAggregator, MessageBus or something similiar.